# Receiving data back from a BLE embedded device on Android

Tags: android, ios, iphone, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on an Android BLE project.  We are using BLE to configure some settings on an embedded device.  The embedded device was going to take a long time to come up so I started using [BlueSim](https://github.com/AttackPattern/BlueSim) to emulate the embedded connection.

There are essentially two messages that the Android (I'm requiring KitKat) device sends off to the embedded device.  One is to write settings....One is to read the settings.

A Write message is going out to endpoint 0xFFF1 like the following

```
        byte[] data2Send = new byte[11];
        data2Send[0] = 0xAA; // signifying this is a write message to device
        data2Send[1] = 0x01; // data value
        data2Send[2] = 0x38; // data value
        data2Send[3] = 0x47; // data value 
        data2Send[4] = 0x24; // data value
        data2Send[5] = 0x01; // data value
        data2Send[6] = 0x36; // data value
        data2Send[7] = 0x49; // data value
        data2Send[8] = 0x0b; // data value
        data2Send[9] = 0x63; // data value
        data2Send[10] = 0x0D; // CR to indicate the last byte of the packet

        characteristic.setValue(data2Send);
        boolean status = mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
        Log.v(TAG,"Status is:" + String.valueOf(status));
```

I had verified this using BlueSim and we have confirmed that this works when transmitting data to the embedded device.  We can successfully change all of the settings.

The other message is a Read request of the device so I can know what settings are already in there or to confirm that the settings actually changed.......

```
        byte[] data3Send = new byte[3];
        data3Send[0] = 0x55; // Signify this is a start of a READ message
        data3Send[1] = 0x42; // Second part of the read designator
        data3Send[2] = 0x0d; // Carriage return saying this is the last bit


        characteristic.setValue(data3Send);
        boolean status = mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
        Log.v(TAG,"Status is:" + String.valueOf(status))
```

When I send this message over to BlueSim, I see the message on my iPhone and immediately send the settings back out.  On Android I see the 11 bytes that are coming back informing me of all the settings!   This almost happens instantaneously. Great!

But when we do this on the embedded device I see one byte come back.  That's it. Using a debugger on the embedded side we can see all 11 bytes going into the BLE module on the embedded device. If we use a PC rather than my Android device we can see all 11 bytes show up on the PC (the manufacturer of the BLE module has a terminal like app that you can 'sniff' the data with).

The embedded device is an 8 bit micro that is hooked up to a BLE module (TI CC2540 chipset) via a UART so it's obviously SLOWER than the iPhone where BlueSim is running.  The embedded device is going to need some time to receive the BLE message, process the request, and shove data back out the BLE module.  Is there some setting I have to set in my Android program to allow for a slower response to come back?

I tried downloading [LightBlue](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lightblue-explorer-bluetooth/id557428110?mt=8) on iOS and sending that read request out, and we get the same results.  We see the first byte of the data packet show up in LightBlue.  But only that one.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as always.

Comment: Ok.  Upon further review.....when I looked at the getProperties() call on Android.....when I'm working with BlueSim on the iPhone the connection lists the properties as 0x18 (WRITE & NOTIFY).  But when I make the connection with the TI Module the only property byte that is set is the NOTIFY property.  How do you interact with a BLE device who is only broadcasting a NOTIFY property?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are experiencing an issue with the TI Module, not Android. Not sure if its the same issue, but it seems others have been getting headaches from trying to establish connections from Android to the CC254X. See here: https://e2e.ti.com/support/wireless_connectivity/f/538/t/401240

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Jel.  I'm going to pass this info along to the team working on the Embedded side.  I'm going to write up a quick iOS app to see if that doesn't have a problem as well (although the LightBlue app on iOS seems to have the same issue).